# Vien siddur (oberlander)

Tags: prayer-book, nusach-ashkenaz

does anybody know what siddur they use in the Viener shul in boro park today?
I realize that there is no specific Oberlander siddur out today and I'd like to get as close as possible.
thnaks

Comment: i think they use regular qol yaa3qob. dont remember since last i was tehre